# Remote and control desktop

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm designing a simple application for remote and control desktop, and really it worked but just in local network.
what should I do to reach a server outside my local network?
I used TCP/IP protocol and used a port number=6600
I tried a public IP using  "what is my IP " site but it didn't work
please I need a help

Comment: Search the web for "port forwarding".

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make yourself reachable. You need to either get your provider to assign you a fixed IP address (not always possible) or you can get a Dyndns account somewhere (like at www.dyndns.org, but there are many), and configure your router to update that Dyndns when it logs in to your provider.

Once that works, and you can test it with a ping from outside your network, you can worry about mapping the right ports on your router's firewall to the machine you want to log into.

I am assuming here you are trying to reach a machine inside your network from outside. It is not really clear from your problem description exactly what you want.